# Using Substring in C# reverse

Tags: c#, substring

And I have filepath say "\ABC\ABX\file.pdf".
How can I get only the folder path i.e. "\ABC\ABX\" using substring any other way.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why you cannot use `Path.GetDirectoryName(....)`?

Comment: you must use the Substring function? Hint: last index of `/`

Comment: thank you i didn't know that existed in c#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `System.IO.Path` class

```
var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"\ABC\ABX\file.pdf");
```

Comment: It might be the better way, but the question specifically states to use Substring.

Comment: This is a much better approach than using substring

Comment: @sharpcloud But he/she also says `thank you i didn't know that existed in c#`

Comment: Ah yes, I thought he said that to the comment directly above. But it didn't state a method name (although I read LastIndexOf in my mind :P ).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a combination of [`Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [`LastIndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
string path = @"\ABC\ABX\file.pdf";
string directory = path.Substring(0, path.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1);
```

It would also be ideal to add a check to ensure that the path even contains a `\`, and because of the `+ 1` you would also want to check that the `\` is not already the last character. Of course though, it would be better to not need such string manipulation in the first place, but I don't know what your exact scenario is

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`Path.GetDirectoryName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx)

```
var directoryOnly = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(@"\ABC\ABX\file.pdf")
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/WDVD42852

Answer (score 0):

There are nicer ways to do this using System.IO, but purely string manipulation:

```
string path = @"\ABC\ABX\file.pdf";
string folder = path.Substring(0, path.LastIndexOf(@"\"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string result = test.Substring(0, test.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
```